# Type has no matching index signature for type 'string'.(2537)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

my code for reference:

```
const MyArray = [
  { name: "Alice", age: 15 },
  { name: "Bob", age: 23 },
  { name: "Eve", age: 38 },
];

type Name = typeof MyArray[string]["name"]; //throws error as Type '{ name: string; age: number; }[]' has no matching index signature for type 'string'
type Age = typeof MyArray[number]["age"] //no error
```

I am trying to access the name as like age. then why I am getting this error. any one help me to understand please?

Thanks in advacne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the name like you're accessing age, you can do `typeof MyArray[number]["name"]`. This is because the array indices are numbers.

Comment: then why this is not works for me? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1oQC5lwEthoBzAJwHsBXAB2gF50ttoBBEYgUwC4AKAJSMAfNGCUAdhEoguAOhCVSfAOQALQioEsAvhj0YMhCbi7kAZmGBc48NuXJh4ABSr1M2CWAC2vPOWNSAG4WMFJeCWpvACMzfUNxKVxbe0d4HgRUp1dKWgBtAF1GaDyWNGgvXx5oACIObhqAGmgw3mgARgBWaB1GsoqfNpqAIUpoppbw6oAmAGYevuxyyqGAUQA3LgnW6tmADgWMApDDc0pyPllksYAraEpzFIcnIQ9bZEgIOQoafNuWmC4eC0LgPJ5pPKRGJmAp5GorGoFAr6IA can you help me please?

Comment: Your obj in the last loop is an object. You can't use an object to index an object. You should use `obj.name`. And you should type the group object as `group: Record<string, any>`. Replace `any` with whatever you want it to be.

Comment: @user2024080 [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1oQC5lwEthoBzAJwHsBXABwC5oAlAU2EvIBMAePcwgHakANNDAD4APmgBedFmzQAgiGIt6ACgCUs6ewERKIFgDoQlUhoDkAC0JWtCgL4YXGQbhbkAZmGAs4eCVycjB4AAUqWnlsATAAW3U+QVIAbgUwUnUBaniAIy9XDAx9PEDg0Ph6BAqwyMpaAG0AXVloRoU0aDjExgAiFTU+0Uz1aABGAFZoJ2FO7oSxvoAhSjzhsSzGACYAZhm57C6epYBRADcWDdHGXYAOA4xm9OLvDg1jXGg1gCtv73KITCOkw2AQyEgEBMFBoTV+JhOzVcQA)

Comment: how to avoid any? since I am getting error from aslant?